# Value Error : need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python

I am working on a word count program.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

# maps words to their counts
word2count = {}

# input comes from STDIN
for line in sys.stdin:

    line = line.strip()


    word, count = line.split('\t', 1)

    try:
        count = int(count)
    except ValueError:
        continue

    try:
        word2count[word] = word2count[word]+count
    except:
        word2count[word] = count

for word in word2count.keys():
    print '%s\t%s'% ( word, word2count[word] )
```

Error for this code:

```
    word, count = line.split('\t', 1)
ValueError : need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Comment: It means there are no tabs in `line`.

Comment: I have checked with tabs also, same error

Comment: What do you mean, _also_? What were you trying originally?

Comment: have a look at [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), it let's you do: `c = Counter()` and then `c['foo'] += 1` without checking first if there's a key `foo`

Answer (score 0):

Moving `word, count = line.split('\t', 1)` in the `try`-`except` should work:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    try:
        word, count = line.split('\t', 1)
        count = int(count)
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

This would skip all the lines that do not have a number at the beginning of the line that is separated with a tab from the rest of the line.

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer if it solves your problem.